# How to reduce the number of queries to the database?

Tags: mysql, hosting

Today I received a letter from the hosting that my site is constantly exceeding the allowed limit of requests to the database. If I don’t solve the problem, they’ll disable my site.

[image]

There is a small traffic on my site - 4-10 visitors per day. And increasing the limit will not solve the problem (since I already did it). How can I reduce the number of queries to the database?

Here are screenshots from the latest events.

Access_log

[image]

Error_log

[image]

Comment: 1000 calls a day is your limit? That's tiny! I suspect that bots are simply eating  your usages. I would suggest that a service with only 1000 calls (at most) a day is designed for private use; not something open to (be viewed by) the public .

Comment: If you don't need the site to be indexed by search engines you could disable crawlers: http://www.robotstxt.org/faq/prevent.html. Otherwise you could put behind simple Auth Basic https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/PasswordBasicAuth. Or get a bigger hosting package :)